# How to shift the specific element in array at the end without sorting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was trying to shift array element which contain 0 elements at the very end whenever it was found in the array. So, I have the below array, just wanted to know how we can shift all 0 elements at the end without sorting the element. Non-zero element order should not get affected. I was able to place 0 elements at the end using the sorting method but was unable to other solutions to achieve the expected output below.

Can anyone look into that sample how we get the expected output?

Sample Array

```
const arr = [4,5,1,0,3,8,0,9,2,0,4]
```

Expected output

```
const arr = [4,5,1,3,8,9,2,4,0,0,0]
```

Comment: By mutating the array or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 `filter`

```js
const arr = [4, 5, 1, 0, 3, 8, 0, 9, 2, 0, 4]
const specificElement = 0

const res = [
  arr.filter(el => el !== specificElement),
  arr.filter(el => el === specificElement),
].flat()

console.log(res)
```

Or 1 `filter`

```js
const arr = [4, 5, 1, 0, 3, 8, 0, 9, 2, 0, 4]
const specificElement = 0

let res = arr.filter(el => el !== specificElement)
res = res.concat(Array(arr.length - res.length).fill(specificElement))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is to create a new, empty array and then loop over the data from end to beginning, putting each element onto either the beginning (with `unshift`) or end (`push`) of the new array depending on whether it's `0`.

```js
const arr = [4, 5, 1, 0, 3, 8, 0, 9, 2, 0, 4];
const result = [];

for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i] === 0) {
    result.push(arr[i]);
  } else {
    result.unshift(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```